# how to install gitweb on redhat

Tags: git, gitweb

How do i install Gitweb on Redhat?

> Red Hat version is 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5  , x86_64 machine.
>   Git version is 1.7.10-rc4

I downloaded the gitweb-1.7.9.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm file and ran the command as below.

> rpm -i /home/user/gitweb-1.7.9.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
>   warning: /home/user/gitweb-1.7.9.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 6b8d.... 
>   error: Failed dependencies:
>           git = 1.7.9.6-1.el5.rf is needed by gitweb-1.7.9.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64

Is there some good documentation or steps where i can set up Gitweb?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo yum install gitweb
```

`yum` will look up the package in the repositories and will take care of the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First install "Webtatic" repo. In my experience, this is quite up to date. To do this:

`rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm`

(Assuming you have RHEL 5) **NOTE** in your question the RedHat version you talk about is the Linux Kernel version. To get RedHat version `cat /etc/redhat-release`

`yum install git-core gitweb`

Let me know if you hit any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Installation is pretty easy. Just one single command would do everything.

gitweb is available in the EPEL repo http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL.

To add Epel repository to your system open a terminal and as root run:

For RedHat/centos 6

`rpm -ivh http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/fedoraproject.org/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

For RedHat/centos 5

`rpm -ivh http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`

Once you have add the Epel repository install gitweb with the command

`yum install gitweb gitweb-caching.noarch`

Or

Try the advanced search at http://rpm.pbone.net/ to find where you can get a gitweb package from.